# How do I have a single instance of vim, without using DISPLAY?

Tags: vim, remote-access

I've used remote-tab for a while, but now I've switched to doing remote coding, on terminal only systems.

Using `--remote-tab` now always has the error: `DISPLAY send failed` .

Does anyone have any luck using a single instance of vim, while not using a display?

Comment: See `:help x11-clientserver`.

Comment: That did not help me.

Comment: 2 questions now, in order to answer the question in my post. 

How do I specify vim to run on a specific display, using a remote terminal?

Why does vim require X server at all?

Is there no way to have a single instance of vim while running in a terminal only?

Comment: #1: You make sure `DISPLAY` is set and you let Vim do what it has to do. #2: Because it makes IPC easier. #3: You already know the answer: no. But that's the wrong question to ask. The right question is "What can I do to have a single instance of Vim in a non-graphical environment?", which can't be fully answered without a number of informations missing from your question, like the *full* output of `$ vim --version`, what system you use, etc. but the fourth paragraph of the help section I mentioned a few days ago as lots of hints.